# Long formula as a matrix coefficient

Tags: matrices

I would like to write a 2*2 matrix with one of the coefficients given by a very long formula that I would like to write on two lines.

I tried this

```
 \begin{displaymath}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    X & X \\
\parbox[c]{3cm}{a+b+c+d\\ +e+f+g+h+j+t\\E+G+T+F+E} & X
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{displaymath}
```

But I am not very satisfied with it. I was hoping some function or package exist to do something cleaner.

How can I do it?

Comment: Please, be so kind and show us what you try so far. Perhaps some of the  `amsmath` or `mathtools` math environments  can solve your problem.

Comment: Please, edit your question and add to it an MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document with your matrix only, which reproduce problem. MWE preamble let be restricted to packages relevant to your problem. Help us to help you.

Comment: Is it really the case that there is no plus sign at the beginning of the third line, before the "`E`"?  This has resulted in at least one questionable result in the answers already given.

Answer (score 3):

One of `amsmath` can be a solution for your problem. However, you can introduce a new variable in your matrix as shown in the MWE below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{pmatrix}
            X   & X \\
\begin{gathered} a+b+c+d\\
                 {}+e+f+g+h+j+t\\
                 E+G+T+F+E
\end{gathered}  & X
  \end{pmatrix}
\]

or
\[
  \begin{pmatrix}
    X   & X \\
    Y   & X
  \end{pmatrix}
\]
where $Y=a+b+c+d +e+f+g+h+j+t E+G+T+F+E$

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**

For the first example, someone may have liked that the long equation is written in a more condensed way. This can be achieved for example by use of `matrix` instead of `gathered` written with a `\small` font size:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
            X   & X     \\[1ex]
\small\begin{matrix}
    a+b+c+d+e\\
    {}+f+g+h+j+t\\
    E+G+T+F+E
\end{matrix} & X
  \end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 2nd option is better by far.

Comment: @Joce, I am of the same opinion. That is reason why I add this possibilities. Thank you for comment!

Answer (score 2):

I guess you've provided an actual use case for drawing horizontal and vertical lines to bring out the structure of the 2x2 matrix.

The following solution uses no extra packages, just a pair of basic `array` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  \left(
  \begin{array}{@{}c|c@{\,}}
     X & X \\
     \hline
     \begin{array}{@{}c@{}}  
        a+b+c+d\\ 
        +e+f+g+h+j+t\\
        +E+G+T+F+E 
     \end{array} 
       & X      
  \end{array}
  \right)
\] 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the same style of [the image of Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/619888/long-formula-as-a-matrix-coefficient/619897#619897), here I add another option using the `matrix` environment. I think that with the `nicematrix` package it is possible to realize similar output.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
  \left(\begin{array}{c|c}
     X & X\\ \hline
       \begin{matrix} a+b+c+d\\
        +e+f+g+h+j+t\\
        +E+G+T+F+E \end{matrix} &  X
  \end{array}\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]